# I want to show my featured image in middle of my post automatically

Tags: wordpress, image, blogs, posts, wordpress-featured-image

I want to show my featured image in middle of my post.
I already have:

```
<?php  
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail();
   } 
?>
```

in my file `content-single.php`.
It displays the featured image in top of my post.
But I want to display featured image in middle of my blog-post automatically.
How can I write code for it? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: show your code. what you tried yet.

Comment: `<div>
 <?php  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

        the_post_thumbnail();
    }?>

    <div class="entry-content">

        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'shape' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

</div>`
@DeepKakkar

Comment: can you show page link? i think you need to edit CSS

Comment: currently i am doing it in localhost.

Comment: [link](http://michaelhyatt.com/blogging-gone-bad.html) check this blog post, there is a text followed by image, followed by text again.
how can i do it manually?

Comment: That site is most likely using a custom field to create that short paragraph above the image. I'm sure there's a way to crack open the_content, and insert something after the end of the first </p> tag, but it doesn't look like that is what that site is using.

Comment: i have a idea that i want to display featured image after p.first-child?
i am a newbie. how can i code it to display featured image after p.first-child?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask